# How to draw the force chart in d3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and when I learnt how to draw a force chart, I had some problems about it. And at first, let we see my code here:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>the force chart</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var width = 400;        
        var height = 400;    
        var svg = d3.select("body")    
                    .append("svg")     
                    .attr("width",width)      
                    .attr("height",height);     
        var nodes = [ { "id": "English" },{ "id": "Italy" },
                      { "id": "America" },{ "id": "Canada" },
                      { "id": "Australia" },{ "id": "Japan" },
                      { "id": "China" } ];
        var edges = [ { "source": 0 , "target": 1 } , { "source": 0 , "target": 2 },
                      { "source": 0 , "target": 3 } , { "source": 1 , "target": 4 },
                      { "source": 1 , "target": 5 } , { "source": 1 , "target": 6 }, ];


        var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)  
                    .force("link",d3.forceLink()
                    .id(function(d){return d.id})
                    .distance(function(d){return 150}).strength([-400]))
                    .force("charge",d3.forceManyBody())
                    .force("center",d3.forceCenter(width , height));

            force.restart(); //start

        var svg_edges = svg.selectAll("line")
            .data(edges)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .style("stroke","#ccc")
            .style("stroke-width",1);

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

        //add nodes
        var svg_nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("r",20)
            .style("fill",function(d,i){
                return color(i);
            })
            .call(d3.drag());   //to drag the nodes

        //add information
        var svg_texts = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("dx", 20)
            .attr("dy", 8)
            .text(function(d){
                return d.id;
            });

        force.on("tick", function(){ //update the position of lines
            svg_edges.attr("x1",function(d){ return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1",function(d){ return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2",function(d){ return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2",function(d){ return d.target.y; })

            //update the position of nodes
            svg_nodes.attr("cx",function(d){ return d.x; })
                .attr("cy",function(d){ return d.y; });

            //update the position of information
            svg_texts.attr("x",function(d){ return d.x; })
                .attr("y",function(d){ return d.y; });

        });
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

I want to draw a picture like this:
[image]

But my code can only show one node, just like this:

[image]

So I feel confused, because there is no error in Developer Tools. As I layout the force, I infer to https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#links . So I solve the problem which is result from the different versions. But why it still doesn't work? Could you help me? I'm very appreciate it if you help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code

firstly you need to append circle like this

```
  var svg_nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")

        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r",20)
        .style("fill",function(d,i){
            return color(i);
        })
        .call(d3.drag());   //to drag the nodes
```

where as your code append r which is no SVG tag moreover the center of the graph should not be width and height it should be width/2 and height/2 to make it at center

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/9515/

similarly for lines you are using edges data which don't have the x,y values you need to pass the xy value for drawing lines

For a complete solution note in v3.3 See this https://jsfiddle.net/3uehrfj8/1/ with all nodes and edges

Comment: But I use the edges data in d3 v4, so how I use it ? The force is different from v3.3.

Comment: Thank you for your point, I exactly forget to add the r in my code.

Comment: @Charlie Yes I was about to update that solution in sometime It shall be something like this from here https://plnkr.co/edit/RwhCmYeQHHMiRUeFEQXN?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Besides the points already explained by @Vinod:

```
.append("circle")
```

and

```
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));
```

You have a trailing comma. But the most important is this, to show the edges:

First, add the edges to the simulation:

```
force.force("link")
    .links(edges);
```

And then, change the links id. Right now, there is no property called `id`. So, it should be:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .id(function(d,i) {
        return i
    })
    //the rest of the function
```

Here is a demo:

```js
 var width = 400;
 var height = 400;
 var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);
 var nodes = [{
     "id": "English"
 }, {
     "id": "Italy"
 }, {
     "id": "America"
 }, {
     "id": "Canada"
 }, {
     "id": "Australia"
 }, {
     "id": "Japan"
 }, {
     "id": "China"
 }];
 var edges = [{
     "source": 0,
     "target": 1
 }, {
     "source": 0,
     "target": 2
 }, {
     "source": 0,
     "target": 3
 }, {
     "source": 1,
     "target": 4
 }, {
     "source": 1,
     "target": 5
 }, {
     "source": 1,
     "target": 6
 }];


 var force = d3.forceSimulation()
     .force("link", d3.forceLink()
         .id(function(d,i) {
             return i
         })
         .distance(function(d) {
             return 150
         }))
     .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
     .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));

 force.restart(); //start

 var svg_edges = svg.selectAll("line")
     .data(edges)
     .enter()
     .append("line")
     .style("stroke", "#ccc")
     .style("stroke-width", 1);

 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

 //add nodes
 var svg_nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
   .attr("r", 20)
     .style("fill", function(d, i) {
         return color(i);
     })
     .call(d3.drag()); //to drag the nodes

 //add information
 var svg_texts = svg.selectAll("text")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("text")
     .style("fill", "black")
     .attr("dx", 20)
     .attr("dy", 8)
     .text(function(d) {
         return d.id;
     });
   
 force.nodes(nodes);
 force.force("link")
      .links(edges);

 force.on("tick", function() { //update the position of lines
     svg_edges.attr("x1", function(d) {
             return d.source.x;
         })
         .attr("y1", function(d) {
             return d.source.y;
         })
         .attr("x2", function(d) {
             return d.target.x;
         })
         .attr("y2", function(d) {
             return d.target.y;
         })

     //update the position of nodes
     svg_nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
             return d.x;
         })
         .attr("cy", function(d) {
             return d.y;
         });

     //update the position of information
     svg_texts.attr("x", function(d) {
             return d.x;
         })
         .attr("y", function(d) {
             return d.y;
         });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help! It works well, but why do my nodes can't be dragged? Because I added the code:  .call(d3.drag()) . Do I need to add the code "on"? Besides, I can not understand the point: you have a trailing comma. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: The trailling coma is in the `edges`. Regarding the dragging, you have to set the typenames. Check this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: Oh my god！Thank you for your help！I just find the trailing coma in the edges. Thank you for your help again！I will try it again according to the example.